# How to delete an email address from a contact

Tags: outlook, applescript

I have written an AppleScript to delete any email address records in Microsoft Outlook that have a facebook.com domain. This is my script:

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"
    repeat with eachContact in every contact
        set emailList to email addresses of eachContact
        repeat with eachEmail in emailList
            if address of eachEmail contains "facebook.com" then
                delete eachEmail
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

The "delete eachEmail" syntax is incorrect. It throws the following error:

> Microsoft Outlook got an error: Can’t make {address:\"contactname@facebook.com\", type:other} into type specifier." number -1700 from {address:"contactname@facebook.com", type:other} to specifier

How should I delete the email address of the contact?

Comment: Did you try: set address of eachEmail to ""

Comment: I also am interested in the answer to this question.

Comment: @Pat_Morita: Thanks. I just tried it. The script ran without errors, but unfortunately, it did not set the email address to no value. The contact records that had facebook.com emails still have them.

Comment: some properties are read only. try to delete the whole Contact. if that works you may add a New Contact without an email and delete former contac

Comment: Thanks @Pat_Morita. I wanted to delete and recreate the record as the last resort, so to speak. The AppleScript dictionary does not say email address is a r/o property, so I am maybe a bit stubborn but I am still trying to figure out if there is something in my syntax that is wrong. For example, one thought I had is maybe Outlook needs a command to "commit" or "save" the change or I need to "tell" eachContact to set eachEmail in a different way? That said, still stuck.